# Range date time query on embedded list in OrientDB

Tags: list, range, orientdb

I have a structure like this in OrientDB, where each node is a particular user represented by user_id and all their purchase information are kept in the embedded list as shown below.

```
[
 {
  "user_id": 1,
  "purchase_info": [ {
                      "product_id": 100,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  01:50:00"
                   }, 

                   {
                      "product_id": 200,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  10:50:00"
                   }

                   ]
 },

 {
  "user_id": 2,
  "purchase_info": [ {
                      "product_id": 100,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  10:50:00"
                   }, 

                   {
                      "product_id": 300,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  20:50:00"
                   }
                   ]
 },
 {
  "user_id": 3,
  "purchase_info": [ {
                      "product_id": 100,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  04:50:00"
                   }
                   ]
 },
 {
  "user_id": 4,
  "purchase_info": [ {
                      "product_id": 300,
                      "timestamp": "2016-04-26  05:50:00"
                   }
                   ]
 }
]
```

**Now I want to find the users who purchased products within a particular date time range.**

For example, if the date time range is between 2016-04-26  01:00:00 and 2016-04-26  04:55:00 the returning result will be user_id 1 and 3.

I know that to query an embedded list we need to use `WHERE <value> IN <key name>`. However, I couldn't find a way to use a range using that format.

Also for non-range query on timestamp it was not possible to use `asDateTime()`.

For instance this query does not return anything:

```
SELECT from V where "2016-04-26 01:50:00" in purchase_info.timestamp.asDateTime()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select user_id,date from (select user_id,purchase_info.timestamp as date from User unwind date) where date between "2016-04-26 01:00:00" and "2016-04-26 04:55:00"
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to use OrientDB.

1. Don't set product id for a join, but rather create an edge between the product and the user entities. The edge is the "purchase". OrientDB is a graph database. In this way you can cross the relationships from both sides.
2. Don't store dates as string, but rather as datetime, so no conversion is needed in the query. Furthermore if you use a string with the configured datetime format, OrientDB will convert your string to the datetime automatically during query evaluation

If you change the model as suggested above, you could do a query like this:

```
select expand( inV() )
from purchase
where date between "2016-04-26 01:00:00" and "2016-04-26 04:55:00"
```

To get all the user that purchased at that interval, and:

```
select expand( outV() )
from purchase
where date between "2016-04-26 01:00:00" and "2016-04-26 04:55:00"
```

To get all the product sold during that interval.

To have good performance, remember to index the date field in the edge "Purchase" by using a NOTUNIQUE index.